# IIS URL Rewrite for a folder to another web server

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, arr

I have an IIS webserver running a website. I've installed ARR3 to enable routing rules.

I'd like to redirect all the incoming request for the URL *.mydomain/url2redirect/* to an Apache server installed on the same machine where is running SVN.

So in the inbound rule definition I've inserted the following:

- Input: URL path after '/'
- Pattern: *.mydomain/url2redirect/*
- Action Type: Rewrite
- Action URL: https://ip-address:8080/{R:2}

By testing the pattern, I get the desired result, and in the R:2 back reference I get the requested page I need to pass to SVN, but I get always a 404.

"url2redirect" doesn't exist but it should captured by the URL rewrite and forwarded to the Action URL.

I've added any outbound rule. Should I have to add something? what?

I've tried also to add a Reverse Proxy Rule, using the ARR template but, it's completely ignored, therefore I think that the routing is not working at all on IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the url rewrite rule Pattern doesn't match the domain part.

That means mydomain will not include in the Pattern.

If you want to match the url2redirect, you should use below pattern.

```
url2redirect(.*)
```

Then I suggest you could modify your action url as below:

```
 https://ip-address:8080{R:1}
```

Comment: To avoid GZIP issues I've found useful this guide: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-part-2-dealing-with-500-52-status-codes/